# Improve Regex with Groups

Tags: regex

Just getting into regex and I am trying to write a regex for a uk national insurance number example ab123456c.

I've currently got this which works

```
^[jJ]{2}[\-\s]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[\-\s]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[\-\s]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[\-\s]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]$
```

but I was wondering if there is a shorter version for exmaple

```
^[jJ]{2} [ [\-\s]{0,1}[0-9]{2} ]{3} [\-\s]{0,1}[a-zA-Z]$
```

So repeat the **[-\s]{0,1}[0-9]{2}** 3 by wrapping it in some sort of group **[ * ]{3}**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i got you right, your insurance numbers are always two letters, 6 numbers, and a final letter, A,B,C or D? Wouldn't it be the easiest way to try sth. like that

```
/\w{2}\d{6}[A-D]/
```

you catch 2 letters at first with `\w{2}` , then you get 6 numbers with `\d{6}` and you end with a letter from A to D by `[A-D]`

Or, if blanks are impontant, try this

```
 /\w{2}\d\d \d\d \d\d [A-D]/
```

I dont think that shorten it much more would be possible, since when you are trying to use `(\d\d ){3}` it would only repeat the same pattern three times, e.g. `23 23 23`

If you really want to learn RegEx, i suggest you [this tutorial](http://work.lauralemay.com/samples/perl.html), it helped me a lot in the beginning of Regular Expressions

Answer (score 3):

A simple research for a regex tutorial in your favorite search engine (duckduckgo for sure) would give you the answer faster than asking in a forum!

So what you are looking for is a non-capturing group `(?:...)`. You can rewrite your pattern like this:

```
^[jJ]{2}(?:[-\s]?[0-9]{2}){3}[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]$
```

or like this if you use a case insensitive flag/option:

```
^J{2}(?:[-\s]?[0-9]{2}){3}[-\s]?[A-Z]$
```

An other possible way consists to remove all that is not a letter or a digit before (and eventually to use an uppercase function). Then you only need:

```
^J{2}[0-9]{6}[A-Z]$
```

As an aside, I don't understand why you start your pattern with J for the first two letters, since many others letters are allowed according to this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Insurance_number

Other thing, short and efficient are two different things in computing.

for example this pattern will be efficient too and more restrictive:

```
^(?!N[KT]|BG|GB|[KT]N|ZZ)[ABCEGHJ-PRSTW-Z][ABCEGHJ-NPRSTW-Z][0-9][0-9][-\s]?[0-9][0-9][-\s]?[0-9][0-9][-\s]?[A-D]$
```

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version:

```
/^j{2}(?:[-\s]?\d{2}){3}[-\s]?[a-zA-Z]$/i
```

See the [regex online demo](https://regex101.com/r/lS0zC6/1)

Note that

- you do not need to escape `-` inside the character class if it is at the beginning or end of the class (see [*Metacharacters Inside Character Classes*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html))
- you can use a `\d` as a shorthand character class for a digit (see [*Shorthand Character Classes*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html))
- `{0,1}` limiting quantifier can usually be represented as a `?` quantifier (1 or zero occurrences)  (see [*Limiting Repetition*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit))
- The `/i` (or inline modifier version `(?i)` - depending on the engine) can be used to turn `[jJ]` to just `j` or `J` (see [*Specifying Modes Inside The Regular Expression*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html))
- A limiting quantifier can be applied to a whole (better non-capturing) group: `(?:[-\s]?\d{2}){3}` (see [*Limiting Repetition*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit))